# MYSQL summing values of multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I have multiple tables, I can list their rows to my website.

What I want is where last column has same value, I want to add up rows values and list as one line.

What I have:

```
Hioss
AUR
Top
1
1
0
Shen

Hioss
AUR
Top
1
1
0
Shen

Kanani
AUR
Jungle
1
1
0
Reksai
```

I don't want to get data like this.
If last column has same values (Shen) I want to sum int values and show as one line at my website.

What I want to do:

```
Hioss
AUR
Top
2
2
0
Shen

Kanani
AUR
Jungle
1
1
0
Reksai
```

My mysql query:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 UNION SELECT * FROM table2");
```

How can I do it? What  should I do?

Comment: You can wrap your `UNION` query in an outer query that groups/sums them, ie. `SELECT col1, col2, col3, SUM(col4), SUM(col5), col6 FROM (SELECT * FROM table1 UNION SELECT * FROM table2) a GROUP BY col6` (note the `col1`-`col6` are just examples, as you don't give explicit column names)

Comment: all values are listing as 0 0 0 0 00 0 :/

Comment: @Sean col1 col2 col3s are working but sum(colx) are not working ints are listing as 0 0 0 0 others are normal

Comment: i added "as x"s after "sum(x)"s and it worked thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. i dont know the fieldnames. You must change it

```
SELECT fieldnam1,fieldnam2, sum(fieldnam3),fieldnam4
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM table1 
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM table2
) as result
GROUP by fieldnam4;
```

Comment: mysql_query("SELECT player,takim, sum(oynananoyun),sum(win),sum(lose),sum(`kill`),sum(death),sum(assist),sum(cs),sum(gold),sum(goldshare),sum(gpm),sum(egpm),sum(fb),sum(dmg),sum(dmgshare),sum(dpm),sum(wardplaced),sum(wardcleared),sum(wardplacedpm),sum(wardclearedpm),sum(wardplacedshare),sum(wardclearedshare),sum(cspm),sum(dakika),sum(saniye),sum(kp),sum(deathpercentage) 
FROM ( SELECT * tclhafta1mac1 
UNION
SELECT * FROM tclhafta1mac2 ) as result GROUP by champion ");

it gives:
right syntax to use near 'tclhafta1mac1 UNION SELECT * FROM tclhafta1mac2 ) as result GROUP by champion' at line 2

Comment: i was missing "from" i added it but it still doesnt work doesnt give errors but all values are 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: fieldnam1,fieldnam2 working but sum(fieldname3) not working. ints are not working texts are worknig :/

Comment: i added "as x"s after "sum(x)"s and it worked thanks!